# Can we select THE ENTIRE spreadsheet with getRange() on Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

would like to know if it's possible to select the ENTIRE spreadsheet with getRange() ? I'm trying to make an auto-clear of a spreadsheet, here is the code I have :

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName();
  sheet.getRange().clearContent();
}
```

I would like it to clear my entire spreadsheet when I select this option on my menu that I made with that code :

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
     options = [
      {name:"Update", functionName:"runQuery"},
      {name:"Clear Sheet", functionName:"clearRange"}
     ];
 menu.addMenu("Menu", options);
}
```

Unfortunaly when I do the `clearRange`, it says me :

> Cannot find method getSheetByName()

I don't know how to fixe it, I'm trying to make that it takes the current spreadsheet whatever the name is, and same for the clearRange i'm trying to make sure that it clears everything on that spreadsheet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), which returns a range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present.

As extra point, you have to input the sheet name in the brackets.

**Example:**

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked, for my sheet problem I also replaced 

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName();

by

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

and everything works, thanks !

Comment: OK... what about everything even if there is no data? Why, you ask? Because it doesn't recognize checkboxes as data and I'm trying to use `range.removecheckboxes()` to clear all the checkboxes in the sheet.